# XInitThreads() called. Still graphics.h crashes

Tags: c++, multithreading, bgi

When I use  to draw in c++, the frame comes out fine for 2-3 seconds and then crashes saying:

[xcb] Unknown sequence number while processing queue.

[xcb] Most likely this is a multi-threaded client and XInitThreads has not been called

I have called the XInitThreads() befor initgraph()
I use Ubuntu 17.10 and g++ 7.2
There seems to be a problem with Ubuntu while using XInitThreads() from what I saw online.
Is there an alternative drawing method? Or can I fix this problem?

A part of my code:

```
int main()
{
  int gd = DETECT, gm;
  XInitThreads();
  initgraph(&gd, &gm, NULL);
  line(100,100,200,200);
  delay(10000);
  getch();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[See: xcb.freedesktop.org/tutorial](https://xcb.freedesktop.org/tutorial/)

It seems as if you could use this tutorial. My understanding was that graphics.h was a header for functions included a long time ago, with Borland Turbo-C? If the functionality of that library was directly reproduced, it wouldn't be compatible with xcb or Xlib since it took over the framebuffer entirely.

I found the Basic Windows and Drawing tutorial, which you'll find at the link I provided, to be very helpful. After you create a window and map it to the screen, you can draw in it using the primitives, pixel by pixel if you like.